# Foudation grid system not working on Angular Form

Tags: css, angular, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I have done the intsallation of foundation 6 on my Angular and it works fine but I realized the grid system is not working at all. I have made a lot of tweaks and turns but still no luck. Anyone knows why this may be. Thank you.

```
    <div>
    <h3>
        Add A Warehouse
    </h3>
</div>
<form novalidate [formGroup]= "warehouseForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitForm()">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="medium-6 columns">
      <label>Warehouse Name
      <span>
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
      </span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Warehouse Name">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="medium-6 columns">
      <label>Warehouse Country
      <span>
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
      </span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Warehouse Country">
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="medium-6 columns">
      <label>Warehouse Region
      <span>
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
      </span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Warehouse Region">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="medium-6 columns">
      <label>Warehouse City
      <span>
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
      </span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Warehouse City">
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="medium-6 columns">
      <label>Warehouse Address
      <span>
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
      </span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Warehouse Address">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="medium-6 columns">
      <label>Warehouse Street
      <span>
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
      </span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Warehouse Street">
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="medium-6 columns end">
      <label>Warehouse Keeper
      <span>
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
      </span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Warehouse Keeper">
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit" class="success button expanded">Save</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

This is my form , I can say I say my foundation works because the fonts and other things are working. But the grid is just not working.

In the .angular-cli.json

```
 "index": "index.html",
  "main": "main.ts",
  "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
  "test": "test.ts",
  "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
  "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
  "prefix": "app",
  "styles": [
   "../node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/css/foundation.css",
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
    "styles.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
  "../node_modules/foundation-sites/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
  "../node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.js"
  ],
```

Image from code inspection
[image]

Comment: Could you give more information? We cant help you if you dont tell us what is going on exactly

Comment: @Mitta added the code. Trust me I basically dont know what is going on anfd where exactly of my code I should thats why I wrote less. But I hope this can help.

Comment: If you inspect your page in the browser, does it show the css rules for row and column? Are they overridden by anything or are they missing?

Comment: @hagner they completely missing, I dont see any of them there.

Comment: @hagner I have also added an image from the css console maybe it would help to make things clear

Comment: Could you verify if css files are downloaded at all, and that angular tries to download them from the correct folders etc.?

Comment: @hagner how do you mean. But lets say when I add some css rules in my individual css files they do load correctly

Comment: @hagner i can also make the conclusion that foundation is working cos all the input and the buttons are foundations styled

Comment: Guys help would be appreciated

Comment: @user3701188 Did my answer work for you?

Comment: does someone has a solution for this question on scss, mine isnt working on SCSS

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with the version of foundation you've got!

Check what grid system your current install of Foundation is using because the newest version of Foundation comes with their XY Grid enabled when you download the complete package and this wont call the CSS of the old grid!

You'll need to re-download a custom version of Foundation but check 'float grid' when you're downloading it and it will get you back to the older grid system and your code should work!

[image]

Heres a link to download the custom foundation version:
https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/download/

And if you want to learn more about the new XY Grid heres a link: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/xy-grid.html

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

- In case anyone else has an issue with using Foundation Flex Grid:
- Try adding these in your **styles.scss**:(you could read more from [here](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/flex-grid.html))

```
@import "../node_modules/foundation-sites/assets/foundation";

@include foundation-flex-classes;
@include foundation-flex-grid;
```

---

- If that did work, here's how I add foundation to my Angular 8 project:
- Install foundation sites and jQuery:

  - ```
      $ npm install --save foundation-sites jquery
    ```
- Add these in **angular.json** file:

  - ```
      "styles": [
            "src/styles.scss",
            "node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/css/foundation.min.css"
       ],
       "scripts": [
             "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
             "node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.min.js"
       ],
    ```
- Add **$** and **foundation** in **app.component.ts**
   -

  ```
      import { Component } from '@angular/core';
      declare var $: any; // <=========== Add this 

      @Component({
         selector: 'app-root',
         templateUrl: './app.component.html',
         styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
      })
      export class AppComponent {
         title = 'app-frontend';
         ngOnInit(): void {
            $(document).foundation(); // <=========== Add this 
         }
      }
  ```

  - **Ctrl C** and **npm start or ng serve** again to reset the server.